# How many tons of steel were produced in Russia during the Russian Civil War?

Tags: 20th-century, soviet-union, russia, industrial-history, russian-civil-war

I have a specific question that I'm highly interested in. Did Russia have any steel industry during its Civil War (1917 - 1922)? And if so, how big was it?

I know Russia built the trans-siberian railway right before that time, which required steel rails, but I'm not sure if that steel was imported or made domestically.

(I tagged Russia and USSR because it's a transitionary period between them.)

**Edit:** Steel industry is any facility that mixes molten iron with carbon (and optionally other alloys like magnesium). It does **not necessarily** have to be a mill.

**Edit:** Ideally, I'm looking for a number. How many tons of steel were produced in Russia at this time?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Russia_(1892%E2%80%931917)#Stolypin_and_Kokovtsov_governments) "By 1914 Russian steel production equaled that of France and Austria–Hungary," World War and Civil War, especially in Ukraine, probably did not help, but it would still have been major a few years later

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Russia was one of the top metallurgy powers, since Peter the Great who built a lot of industries at Urals. One can argue that Russia was good only in agriculture and metallurgy at the time.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.

Comment: Even if this answer is true, "top metallurgy powers" does not necessarily mean steel. At minimum, it means Russia had a lot of metal mines---iron or copper or some other metals. But those are just **raw** metals. Industrial steel requires a major forge. So sources are needed, ideally quoting how many tons of steel were produced in Russia in a certain year.